# SQLite query results to a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite, python-3.4

I'm trying to store the results of the following query to a dictionary. So far I have managed to store the cost of players selected to a list by doing:

```
total = []

print("--------Midfielders--------")
for player in range(4):

    name=(input("Enter Midfielders name: "))
    role = "Midfielder"

    cursor.execute('''SELECT player, position, cost
                      FROM players
                      WHERE player =? AND position =? ''',(name, role,))
    print (cursor.fetchone())


    cursor.execute('''SELECT player, position, cost
                      FROM players
                      WHERE player =? AND position =? ''',(name, role,)) 
    total.append((cursor.fetchone()[2]))


print(sum(total))


print("-------Forwards--------")
for player in range(4):

    name=(input("Enter Forwards name: "))
    role = "Forward"

    cursor.execute('''SELECT player, position, cost
                      FROM players
                      WHERE player =? AND position =? ''',(name, role,))
    print (cursor.fetchone())


    cursor.execute('''SELECT player, position, cost
                      FROM players
                      WHERE player =? AND position =? ''',(name, role,)) 
    total.append((cursor.fetchone()[2]))


print(sum(total))
```

What I want to be able to do is be able to store the result(player, position, cost) to a dictionary.

Normally I would set a dictionary

```
playerCost = {}
```

and then do something like `playerCost[player],[position]+=cost` to create a dictionary that showes `Rooney Forward : 8.3`. I have tried alsorts of permutations but I'm just guessing how this can be done with cursor.execute. Any Help much appreciated.

Comment: You are returning just the one row per player - position combo; why use `+=` here? What is there to sum in that case?

Comment: The dictionary will hold many players whose total value will be calculated. I will also check that no more than 4 midfielders and 4 defenders are selected etc.

Comment: Your loop already takes care of the number limits. Your total value appears to be the cost of all the players; cost per player isn't taken into account. You can simply create dictionaries here, that's not an issue, but I don't see what you expect from them. `playerCost[player, position] = cost` would create a tuple key, but that's not that helpful if you need to count players for a position.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that. I guess i best just stick to player: position, cost. But whichever way i try i cant get the executed query results in to the dictionary. In the current guise i should get 4 players in but i cant seem to write a single player to the dictionary based on the query results.